# Watcher took too long time to load(NodeWatcher) - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, timeout, node-modules, watchman

I am trying to run already built application in my mobile.  When i start the app with "react-native start" code, it returns the following error message after some time

```
ERROR  Watcher took too long to load (NodeWatcher)
Error: Watcher took too long to load (NodeWatcher)
at Timeout._onTimeout (index.js:99:16)
at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

I am using Windows 7 (32 Bit). I dont find any "Watchman" release for windows 7 32bit system.  Because of this issue, i got the following error after installing my app in mobile

```
Reference Error: Can't find varaible: __fbBatchedBridge
```

Edit: now i have upgrade my system to windows8 with 64bit. But still i was not able to install the watchman.

Comment: What version of react-native and watchman are you using? I think I have your problem resolved, I just need to confirm versions.

Comment: what is your watchman version?

Comment: Is the React Native project director a git repository? how you installed watchman?

Comment: I have downloaded it from here. facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html. It said there is no release for windows 7 32bit system, So i havent installed watchman

Answer (score 2):

You can try to edit a file from react-native packager

```
node_modules\react-native\packager\react-packager\src\FileWatcher\index.js
```

Change the line 17 MAX_WAIT_TIME to 60000.

More [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2841)

Comment: my node_modules\react-native\packager\react-packager\src folder doesnt have FileWatcher. Could you please tell me how to include it?

Comment: @viji This is why I asked for the version you're using. This is likely the problem, but the solution will depend on what you are using.

Comment: @KyleRichardson I have downloaded it from here. https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html

Answer (score 1):

i just want to help you so i think you need to re-install your watchman because I've also had problems with my wachman and the solution I re-install and my program goes back

i hope this answer can help you :)

Comment: I have used this link https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html to download watchman. its not working. Its still showing error.

Answer (score 1):

Changing this passed my test on window

```
node_modules\react-native\packager\react-packager\src\FileWatcher\index.js line 17 MAX_WAIT_TIME to 50000 or higher
```

May be this can help you

Comment: my node_modules\react-native\packager\react-packager\src folder doesnt have FileWatcher. Could you please tell me how to include it?